# Git - Client and Server Repos

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, git-branch, autoscaling

I'm setting up a Client and Server architecture. Because the server REST service will run on AWS, with autoscaling, the instances automatically pull the latest code from the Repo when they run. Because this REST service is a core part of the client, if I end up having to make breaking changes I will create a new branch (ie v2) and this will then end up being on it's own path /api/v2/ on the server (under a different repo), so existing clients will continue to work until they upgrade, at which point i'll end up turning the old branches off on the server.

My question is though, how should I structure this? If I have the Client and Server in one repo, the master may get messy as both Client production releases and Server production releases will end up in commits on it - and also I'll have to have branches for the server like Serverv1, Serverv2 - which seems messy.

So I'm thinking that I might be better off having two repos, one for the server and one for the client. That way the number of branches will be reduced, and the server can have it's own V1, V2 branches etc and the client can have it's own and it's a lot cleaner. However is this the best solution? The client and server will often be built together in tandem because obviously they are quite heavily intertwined, but then with seperate repos it will save the amount of branches and perhaps make it easier to manage? Another advantage would be not needing to use the sparse-checkout option to save downloading the entire source of client and server to the server - the server repo will just contain the server code.

Am I just approaching this whole issue wrong? Because as part of this I'll end up having to commit DLLs to the repo for it to push out on the server, which feels a bit wrong, should I implement Continuous Integration to build it, or is this overkill?

What do you lot think?

Thanks